# How to change status bar colour while using xamarin shell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

I'm using Xamarin Shell to display navigation drawer and some tabs.
I need to change the status bar colour. I searched many solutions but everything works when we don't go for Xamarin shell based navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

We could set the style of Shell navigation bar in Resource Dictionary

```
   <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />  // set navigation bar color here
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it in the Content Page XAML. I prefer it this way when the bar color needs to change for each page, which I do a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="BaseApp.Pages.MainMenuPage"
Shell.BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource GradiantRedToOrange_End}"
Shell.ForegroundColor="White"
Shell.PresentationMode="Animated">
```

To change the nav bar background color

```
Shell.BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource GradiantRedToOrange_End}"
```

To change the title text and nav button color

```
 Shell.ForegroundColor="White"
```